# Next/Done button Editor in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to get the "Done" button working on an Extended Editor I have in Android. I have scoured the internet and I have a code snippet that works for extended entry, but does not for an editor.

```
            Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Done;
            Control.SetImeActionLabel("Done", ImeAction.Done);
```

Any idea what could be done here to get the done button to show up on the keypad?

Comment: You will not be able to use multi-line editor then, correct? If that the case why you don't use an Entry?

Comment: The editor still works as normal. I can use an Entry but I need a multiline editor.

Comment: In multi-line editor you have Enter button. If you change it to done then you will not have multi-line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your point makes sense, but how do we get the keyboard to close once we are done typing.

Comment: The only way I found is to click outside the editor

Comment: or click on hide keyboard in the menu